# Is there a notification of "on hold" and "closed"?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, notifications, on-hold-questions

Perhaps I am mistaken but I think there is no notification of these events when they occur. Should there be one in the notification area?

Comment: You are correct, there is no notification. 

To have such a notification is an old and popular request on MSE 

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed

that however was not yet implemented.

Comment: Wait, WTF??  I'm seriously dumbfounded that there is no such notification.  This seems like a no-brainer.

Comment: @EricWofsey  It seems to  follow the principle that negative events are not brought to the user's attention. In this specific case it is quite at odds with the idea that a question is "put on hold" to be improved though, I agree with this.

Comment: Also, activities on Meta don't seem to show  on Notification.

Comment: That is not my experience. I would not know of any difference between meta and main notifications.

Comment: @quid I could be mistaken but I thought reputations point gains of Math/Meta don't show on Math. I am not sure if they should either.

Comment: There are no reputations points on meta.. Upvotes  on main that do not lead to a change of points do not create a notification either. Thus the behavior is the same.